# How to Remove Super SU

Tags: unrooting

I have tried to root my Galaxy S3. Installed Super SU through flashing. Due to KNOX, I am not able to root my phone. However, the Super SU app remains in my ROM, and I would like to remove it. Help?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "Installed SUPERSU through flashing"? Did you install it via a custom recovery, or through a proprietary flashing tool like odin or Heimdall? Did you follow any tutorial if yes link it. etc.

Comment: Wow... I completely forgotten about this threat. I'm still having problem and now I cannot do a software upgrade. I followed this tutorial. Please help.

http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-root/how-to-root-sprint-galaxy-s3-sph-l710/

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in SuperSU in the settings tab, called Full Unroot, use that and it will remove root from your device.