# How to remove SuperSU when phone is improperly rooted?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access

I attempted to root my Motorola G 2nd Generation, and failed. I tried to remove everything and go back to normal, but the SuperSU app stayed. The phone stated it as an system app. I tried factory resetting, but SuperSU app was still there.

Basically, my phone improperly rooted, and SuperSU won't get installed. I'd like to remove this app.

Using version 5.0.2 of Android, and my system version is 22.21.28.titan_retuaws.retuaws.en.US retus.

Tell me if you need more info.

Comment: You'll have to either flash a ROM or root and remove it.  (I suppose you could craft a custom update.zip to try to excise it as well.)

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87980/how-to-remove-super-su

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery like twrp? You could delete it in the file manager of that. Or use stock recovery and flash the identical rom you have onto your phone. Don't do a factory reset and don't wipe cache

Comment: This is unclear. You wrote that SuperSu is a system app (which means it is installer) but then wrote "SuperSU won't get installed". What does it mean "*my phone improperly rooted*"?

Answer (score 0):

Open the SU app, then scroll down through settings and it has options which optimise the app and root to ready for full unroot.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange the your system contains SuperSU while it's not actually rooted.  It usually requires root access to install any app to the system so you should just have a .bin file to update.   Id you want to remove SU, you'll need to gain root access again and remove the apk after that... You obviously got a correct method of root, but didn't install SuperSU properly, So SuperSU can't manage root permissions, however the method you used to install it to system should be able to remove it as well

Answer (score -2):

Try [Hide My Root](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amphoras.hidemyroot) to uninstall SuperSU.

Comment: This app itself requires root.